# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (6,)

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, classification

I'm trying to run a multi class classification using the following ANN model:

```
classifier = Sequential()
classifier.add(Dense(units = 9, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu', input_dim = 18))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 9, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 9, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
classifier.add(Dense(units = 6 ,kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'softmax'))
classifier.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100) 
y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

where format of X_train is :

```
[[31 8 27 ... 2 7 5]
 [31 8 11 ... 1 9 3]
 [6 0 4 ... 1 9 3]
 ...
 [55 55 134 ... 5 5 6]
 [41 9 111 ... 1 3 0]
 [19 9 28 ... 3 0 0]]
```

and y_train is :

```
[[0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Shape of X_train is (352, 18) and shape of y_train is (352, 6) and shape of X_test is (152, 18).

When it's run, it gives the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\p36564\Project ZS\tst1.py", line 110, in <module>
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = 10, epochs = 100)
  File "H:\p36564\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 950, in fit 
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "H:\p36564\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 787, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "H:\p36564\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py", line 137, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (6,)
```

What could be possible reasons for this error? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `y_train` shaped as you provide it, use `categorical_crossentropy` as a loss function instead of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. Your `y_train` is one-hot encoded and not sparsely encoded. A sparse encoding in your case would be an array that looks as follows:

```
[3, 4, 4, ..., 5, 5, 5]
```

To try this out for yourself, convert `y_train` to a sparse encoding as follows:

```
y_train_ = np.argmax(y_train, axis=1)
```

This will work with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as a loss function (without needing the change the model architecture!)